# Are there boost make_shared_array and make_scope or only make_shared?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

Are there boost `make_shared_array` and `make_scope_ptr` or only [`make_shared`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::make_scoped_ptr` wouldn't work, since you can't transfer ownership from a `scoped_ptr`. At least, not without an explicit call to `swap`.

And with Boost 1.53, there's not much reason to use `shared_array`, since you can just use `shared_ptr` with an array type. So just use `boost::make_shared`.